# How to set same id for multiple rows in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have a table named `wp_shortcode`. When a form is data from the form will be inserted to multiple rows into the table. Below given is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="form1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate"><br>
    Post Type
    <select class="taxonomy">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Category
    <select class="cat">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <h3>Questions</h3>
    <button class="new_btn">Add New</button><br>
    <div class="add_ques">
        <span>Question1</span>
        <textarea name="ques1" id="ques1"></textarea>
        <br>
        Option1
        <select class="option" name="opt1" id="opt1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

The add_ques div section will be multiplied on add new button click.I need to insert the data from the form to `wp_shortcode` table.Currently the table have `s_id`,`post_types`,`category`,`question`,`option` columns.

How can i add a common `id` to the rows generated during form submission.

Comment: I assume `s_id` is an autoincrement column right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes `s_id` is an autoincrement column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:
I add an addition column `group_id` to the table. And when we submit the form we will check `group_id` values:

```
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT group_id FROM $table_name");
$siz = sizeof($post_id);
$index = $siz-1;
$gid = $post_id[$index];
$group = $gid->group_id;
$group_id = (int)$group;
```

And last `group_id` value is checked:

```
if($group_id == 0){
    $id = 1;
}
else{
    $id = $group_id+1;
}
```

This `id` is inserted along with other values into table. By this set of data inserted during of form submission will get same `id`.

Answer (score 0):

The field name should be an array, then you will get the values in post array in PHP ($_POST['ques'] and $_POST['opt'])Try this:

```html
<div class="add_ques">
 <span>Question1</span>
 <textarea name="ques[]" id="ques1"></textarea><br>
 Option1<select class="option" name="opt[]" id="opt1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 </select><br>
</div>
```

Also, the id of the fields should be unique.

Comment: I dont have issue with the field `id`. Field id's generated are unique. Thanku for ur effort and I have found the solution for the question.